# Exception not being caught by Promise.prototype.catch()

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In the code below, if I insert the line `throw "Error";` at the very start of the ajax function then the exception is captured by the catch and dispatchError is called. However if it is thrown within the xhttp.onreadystatechange arrow function the exception is not caught. Why?

```
   let ajax = (url, cb, data) => {

    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
            let data;
            if (xhttp.responseText) {
                data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            }
            cb({status: xhttp.status, data});
        }
    };

    xhttp.open(data?"POST":"GET", url, true);

    if (data) {
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
        xhttp.send();
    }
};

export const getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ajax("url",response => response.status===200?
            resolve(response.data):
            reject(new Error("Error"))
        );
    });


getData()
    .then(d=>dispatchData(d))
    .catch(e=>dispatchError(e))
```

Comment: It's because `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous, throwing an error inside the `onreadystatechange` is too late

Comment: @adeneo What should I be doing so to capture all exceptions?

Comment: First you'll have to define what an "exception" is. What could go wrong with the ajax call, other than not returning a 200 response? Why would you throw errors in that function etc? The way you've defined the `ajax` function, it would be more common to check the status code and any thing else that could go wrong inside the `ajax` function, and then do `cb(error, result)` where you just pass `null` in the first argument if everything is okay,

Comment: @adeneo Suppose xhttp.responseText does not contain json then an exception will be generated which I would like to catch.

Comment: Then you should wrap `JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)` with `try...catch`, it is always as simple as that.

Comment: Something like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/vymryphb/

Comment: Ok, thanks @adeneo.